# Generating tags for python that follow imports

Tags: ctags, filetype-python

I'd like to be able to conveniently navigate to the file where a Python value (function/class/constant) is defined. Most of the guides I can find for using ctags with Python suggest options that aren't supported by the various ctags-like programs that I've found.

I've tried using vanilla ctags (`/usr/bin/ctags` on OS X), exuberant ctags (through brew), and etags (on OS X) to generate `tags` files for a Python project and have been somewhat dissatisfied with the out of the box results.

If I navigate to the project root and run `ctags -R .` I get a lot of lines like the following:

```
version_info    api-docs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/chardet/__init__.py /^from sys import version_info$/;"  i
```

A line like

```
from sys import version_info
```

appears literally in the Python source code.

The symbol `version_info` is defined in the `sys` module, which should be somewhere in the standard library in my virtualenv. When you do an unqualified import in Python, you really are copying the contents of the symbol to a new symbol in the current module, but most of the time I just want to jump to the place where the symbol was originally defined.

I get that the actual place where a symbol is defined depends on information only available at runtime like the `PYTHONPATH`, but a heuristic guess is better than nothing (there might also be a nice interface for cycling between symbols that are defined in multiple files built in to vim, I'm not sure).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about Vim, but about ctags.

Comment: A quick internet search on "ctags python" brought [python-ctags 1.0.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ctags), which you may find useful. The search also shows [this guide](http://tartley.com/?p=1277), which explains how to disable import tags (such as the `version_info` you mentioned that are bothering you).